# Source Tree doesn't launch after installation

Tags: sourcetree

After successful download of source tree on windows 10 , the application doesn't seem to launch, Any help appreciated , Thanks

Answer (score 128):

For me it was sufficient to delete the two Cache files

- Assemblies.cache
- Composition.cache

in

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_<random_string>\<version_number>
```

That way I didn't need to reinstall or reconfigure my Sourcetree.

Comment: That helped for me. Files were recreated on the next start and app is working again

Comment: Also for me.  I see we've all commented recently to this very old thread.  For me, I suspect that recent monthly update to Windows 11 (June 23) is the culprit.

Comment: I'm one of the lucky people to get this answer, I didn't reinstall Sourcetree. Terima kasih :)

Comment: This was the issue in my case.

Comment: That helped me. Very simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion - can confirm that it worked for me without having to re-configure anything.

Comment: Thanks, helped me without losing all my settings. I just wonder how can an app written so badly that it does not even report an error but silently crashes/quits.

Comment: Having used this software for years, it has just done the same for some reason. Thank you for the resolution!

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me when Source tree suddenly stopped opening when it was working previously.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this, pretty straightforward and useful

Comment: @DanHaywood this happened to me after a system upgrade on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Answer (score 39):

[This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/sourcetree-crashes-on-startup-831655339.html) solved the issue for me.

> **Cause**
>
> The most likely reason for this error is that the user.config file for SourceTree has been corrupted.
>   You can confirm this by locating the file in this location: `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_<random_string>\<version_number>`
>
> If this is the cause, when you open the file, it will be full of `<NULL>` values.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> If the user.config file is indeed corrupted, you may delete it.
>   It will be regenerated the next time you start SourceTree, and the application should start normally.

Comment: great answer. Thanks

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case I had several different such folders with many previous version numbers within them. Located the one with the latest version number - the `user.config` file within looked normal and not corrupt. However I renamed it to `backup SourceTree.exe_<random_string>` and this did the job.

Comment: This answer really helped me

Comment: Still works in 2023 as a work around.  It's unfortunate that these files are still getting corrupted.

Comment: @shawn1874 something must have broken in the past few days cause this answer is suddenly getting massive attention. Interesting.

Answer (score 8):

Without providing the SourceTree errorlog nobody will really be able to tell you how to resolve this issue.

The Sourcetree errorlog can be found at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\sourcetree.log` on windows.

Or by opening the Console application (Applications >> Utilities >> Console) and searching for entries related to "SourceTree", on mac.

The 2 most common fixes however are:

- Re-install Source tree.
- Delete the `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Atlassian` folder

[Sourcetree.log](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/sourcetree-logfile-location-675384748.html)

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me: Delete the C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Atlassian folder

Answer (score 6):

1. Check the logs of sourcetree which is placed in  %AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
2. In my case it was:
   ERROR [2023-06-15 14:07:37,286] [1] [Sourcetree.Composition.VSMef.Net471.VSMefCompositionManager] [Log] - Unable to load MEF components
   System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements....
3. Solution:
   Delete file which is located in the following path:
   %AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_some_random_value\here should be your version of source tree in my case it was 3.4.5.0\Composition.cache

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to start the installer. After running it, SourceTree just opens again. No installation was triggered. Afterwards it opens again without any problems.
Version 3.4.13

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall .Net 4.5 Or your current .Net version
2. Install SourceTree 2.4.7.0 (Sourcetree installation will install .Net Again for you).

Note: I tried Atlassian recommendations such as deleting \Users{UserId}\AppData\Local\SourceTree as well as \Users{UserId}\AppData\Local\Atlassian. Also tried Deleting entries from Windows Registry none of those things helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the banner flashes for couple of seconds and then gone, you need to update the user.config file.
It happened after the windows update.
go to sourcetree path:
C:\users\admin\AppData\local\Atlasian\SourceTree.exe\3.4.11.0\

delete all the contents inside this folder and restart the source tree.

Ps: it is always good to have backup

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the change of installation location between versions of SourceTree. 
As of 3.4.14 it is in **\AppData\Local\SourceTree** 
and not in *\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree*.